# how to convert mp3 file to binary and vice versa on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, mp3

I am trying to convert an mp3 file to binary format then encrypt the converted file, send it over a public network then decrypt it and finally convert it back to its original mp3 format. I am using node JS to implement this.

I read the music file and converted it to its binary form. But when i tried to reverse the process the file is not playable. Can someone tell me why it went wrong ?

Below is the code I have used.

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('music.mp3', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var encodedmp3 = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('binary');

    //perform the encryption, then

    fs.writeFile("music.enc", encodedmp3, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }); 

});
```

Comment: You can't convert arbitrary binary data to a string and expect to get something meaningful.  Why are you trying to convert to a string?

Comment: Luke, that's because I want to encrypt the data by rearranging the elements of the string literal. The problem is when i try to revert the string back to an mp3 file without rearranging the string literal elements, it doesn't work

Comment: You can't express an MP3 file as a string because it is inherently binary data.  A string is a set of bytes encoded in such a way that they can be represented as characters e.g. UTF8 or ASCII.  An MP3 file is not encoded this way because it is not a string, so the result is not valid.

Comment: I'd suggest encoding the binary data in a string format, using base64 or uuencode.